# STTwitter return nil iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, bearer-token, sttwitter

I'm using STTwitter Library (latest version) and trying to get tweets with authenticating by oAuth and specifically using the Application Only authentication which provide the bearer token.
I used the example code provided on GitHub but I do not getting neither success or error on the log out. This is my code :

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:@"XXX"
                                                    consumerSecret:@"XXX"];
[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

[twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"sttwitter"
                          successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
    NSLog("successBlock : ", statuses);
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog("errorBlock : ", error);
}];
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
NSLog("errorBlock : ", error);
}];
```

Any help will be appreciated. I'm unable to find other twitter library specially for the api v1.1.

Comment: STTwitter Not Returning Anything Neither Success or Error and the app continue executing the rest of code. Anybody know what's wrong ?

Comment: [updated](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues/161#issuecomment-72725226)

Comment: [Issue solved on GitHub](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/issues/161).